# Mystery rep point

Tags: support, reputation

I went to [my reputation tab in my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal?tab=reputation) to look at all the recent rep I acquired and it said it added up to `60` but the numbers did not look right:

[image: mystery rep]

I *know* it is only one point, but points **add up**. How do I find out where that extra point came from?

Comment: Did you do this math on the 'time' tab, too?

Comment: @Tichodroma yep.

Comment: If I open it now, i don't even see the +1 from "buttons with different..." question, so it adds up to 58. Anyway, you've _gained_ a point, not _lost_ it :P

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall yea, I know, but they do add up :-P

Comment: @Singer: The +1 is from a removed downvote. Other's downvotes are invisible.

Comment: This is probably just a caching issue.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ nope I don't think so. because if I add up the rep even now from that time period it is still === 59

Comment: I'm saying it's possible the 60 was cached when you actually got +60, but one point went away in the meantime. Anyways, I don't see the point of this question. You have 42k+ rep, why is this important?

Comment: Just like an elitist to think that having a lot of EXP releases them from being concerned with discrepancies of lesser amounts. Attitudes like yours are exactly why bugs of this ilk are never fixed; and, that's precisely one of the reasons why I suggest we re-distribute EXP.

Comment: It's a ghost. OOOOOOOOOOoooooooo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ran across this in the close queue and surprised no one ever *really* answered it. Your reputation change since you last checked *does* add up to +60. Keep in mind that reversal and removed events **do not count** towards that total that shows up in the tab. Your actual values:

```
Date       Change    Total
------------------------------
Oct 26     -10       -10
Oct 27     +0        -10
Oct 28     +25       +15
Oct 29     +25       +40
Oct 30     +20       +60
```

And voilà!

Answer (score 9):

I went to check my own rep tab here on Meta to see if I could reproduce this, and found:

[image: obviously fake reputation increase]

Obviously, the person responsible for calculating and updating these numbers is getting lazy, and they probably can't be trusted to have more than a tenuous connection to what you've actually earned. I recommend punishing him by visiting your profile more often, thus forcing him to type more until he starts getting it right.

Comment: I [got bigger](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uE8j9.png)! :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd that's.... what... _she_... said?

Comment: @ama shh! It's a secret.

Answer (score 3):

That tab doesn't show rep earned in the past fixed time period. It shows the net rep change since the last time you clicked on the tab. Are you **sure** you didn't look at it 60 points ago? Your screenshot is difficult to use for figuring this out, since it's sorted by post and not by time.