# Is this reputation change notification displayed as expected?

Tags: bug, reputation-history

I had a quick glance at my English Language and Usage account that I haven't visited in, *ahem*, quite a while and saw this little quirk in the change notification on the reputation tab:

[image: Screenshot of my EL&U reputation tab]

The two new changes sum to a **0** point net change, however the change indicator says **-2**.  Whilst I agree that having the red indicator saying 0 would also be strange behaviour, surely it shouldn't show up at all when there is no net change?

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157327/200500

Comment: @Asad interesting read, the numbers in this case however do add up correctly, it's just a strange way to be informed of the change.

Comment: I should have added some context. What might have happened is that a couple of posts you downvoted (that were deleted) were undeleted, which would subtract two points but leave no visible evidence. There might be a simpler explanation though, this sounds like a stretch.

Comment: @Asad Ahh, the downvote highlighted is on one of *my* questions by someone else that they later reversed. Sorry I should have made that clear!

Answer (score 6):

I'm fairly sure this is by-design. Your reputation change (in the tab) gets updated upon a downvote, to sum to -2 for it. However, when events get reversed, the system doesn't also revert the change in the tab (it's probably a hassle to keep track of what events make up the reputation change you see there, since it resets whenever you dismiss it). This is similar to [what happened in another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153210).

When a downvote gets reversed, **you're not gaining 2 reputation**, the -2 you received before is being *reversed*. The actual undownvote event in your reputation history is just a nice notice so you know why your reputation went back up by 2. Since it's reversing a previous event, it doesn't update the reputation change in the tab. So the -2 is from the downvote only, the undownvote is ignored.

As for whether or not it's a bug, I don't see any reason for the developers to spend much time on this. If it's not a simple fix for them, I'd say let it go. It does reset as soon as you look at your history, after all.